# Insert JSON into Hadoop

Tags: json, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have a lot of data (JSON string) per day (around 150-200B).

I want to insert the JSON to Hadoop, what is the best way to do it (I need a fast insert and a fast query on JSON fields)?

Do I need to use hive and create Avro scheme to my JSON? Or do I need to insert the JSON as a string to a specific column?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: We are not tried so far, we are looking for the best way to do it before we start

Answer (score 2):

> I want to insert the JSON to Hadoop

You just put it in HDFS... Since you have data over a time period, you'll want to create partitions for Hive to read

```
jsondata/dt=20180619/foo.json
jsondata/dt=20180620/bar.json
```

> Do I need to use hive and create Avro scheme to my JSON?

Nope. Not sure where you got mixed up between Avro and JSON. Now, if you could convert the JSON into defined Avro with a schema, then that would help improve Hive queries since querying structured binary is better than parsing JSON text.

> do I need to insert the JSON as a string to a specific column?

Not recommended. You could, but then you cannot query it, via Hive's [JSON Serde support](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde/blob/develop/README.md)

Don't forget with the above structure you'll need `PARTITIONED BY (dt STRING)`. And in order for partitions to be created on the table for existing files, you'll need to manually (and daily) run an `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` command

> i have JSON as string (from kafka)

Don't use Spark for that (at least, don't reinvent the wheel). My suggestion would be to use Confluent's HDFS Kafka Connect that comes with Hive table creation support.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the data available in Hive to perform mostly aggregations on top of it, I would suggest 1 of the following method using spark.

If you have multiple-line json files

```
var df =  spark.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://ypur/hdfs/path/*.json").values)
df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("yourhivedb.tablename")
```

If you have  single-line json files

```
val df = spark.read.json("hdfs://ypur/hdfs/path/*.json")
df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("yourhivedb.tablename")
```

Spark will automatically infer the table schema for you. If you are using cloudera distribution you will be able to read the data using impala (depending on your cloudera version it may not support complex structures)

Comment: Thanks, and if i have JSON as string (from kafka) What do i need to change?

Comment: it depends on what you are trying to achieve ... if you want real time ingestion, it is more complex to keep in sync with Hive structures. I would suggest set a fix layout to load it ...  but that depends a lot on your use case and what you need, ingest data in realtime is much more complex if you want to make it available for analytics in an efficient way

Comment: Yeah, i need to injest data in realtime